# can't login using praw. already checked the credentials

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, reddit, praw

```py
import praw

hey = praw.Reddit(
    client_id="",
    client_secret="",
    user_agent="my user agent",
    user_name="",
    password=""
) 
print(hey.user.me())
hey.subreddit("AskMen").subscribe()
```

### double checked all the crediantials but still getting this error.

And in the output console only "none" is printed

```
praw.exceptions.RedditAPIException: USER_REQUIRED: 'Please log in to do that.'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem was in the statement of "user_name". It should be username not user_name.